# Cordova CLI:an error while adding Android

Tags: cordova

I am facing a problem in cordova version I want to install cordova version 3.5 but it install the latest version and I got problems in it and the problem is it cant run android platform can anybody please tell me about how to download specific version of cordova.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you can download a specific version with `npm install cordova@3.5.0-0.2.7` which installs cordova 3.5 for you.

When you call `npm info cordova` you can see all the valid versions (because there are more 3.5 versions).

This being said, you might want create a new question with the actual error you are having because staying on an older version might not be the best thing.